# Tomcat automatically shut down？

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, hadoop

When I start tomcat in the eclipse program with MapReduce run is complete, tomcat will automatically shut down?

The following is Run log:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Check whether System.exit() is called or not

Comment: Please paste the logs rather than posting an image of them. It makes it much easier for search engines to index your post, and so may help others in the future.